# How to bind data to react table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, html-table

I am first time playing with the React and I would like to connect (id, name, status and quantity):

```
interface Goods {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  status: string;
  quantity?: number;
}

export const getGoods = (): Promise<Goods[]> => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const data = [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "A",
          status: "ready",
          quantity: 15
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "B",
          status: "pending",
          quantity: 25
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "C",
          status: "ready",
          quantity: 10
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "D",
          status: "not ready",
          quantity: 25
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          name: "E",
          status: "ready",
          quantity: 25
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          name: "F",
          status: "ready",
          quantity: 5
        }
      ];

      resolve(data);
    }, 1000);
  });
};
```

To the table body < tbody >:

```
import React from "react";
import { getGoods } from "./data";

export const Abc: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <table className="table table-striped table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">ID</th>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Status</th>
          <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        
      </tbody>

    </table>
  );
};
```

The cherry on the top will be also with the sorting (e.g. with following order: ready, not ready, pending).

Thanks for any help or tip!

Here is sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-torvalds-c343o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Loading Data

Everything in React revolves around the principle of state.  You want to store your goods in state using a `useState` hook.

```
const [goods, setGoods] = React.useState<Goods[]>([]);
```

You will load your data with a `useEffect` hook that and saves it to the component state once the `Promise` has been resolved.  You want an empty dependency array `[]` to run the effect only once.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  // need to define the function and call it separately
  const load = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await getGoods();
      setGoods(data);
    } catch (error) {
      // your Promise won't ever error, but an actual API might
    }
  };
  load();
}, []);
```

In your table, you loop through the `goods` array and render a table row `tr` for each.  Elements in a `map` callback should have a unique `key` property, so I am using `id` as the key.  The table cells `td` should follow the same order as your columns.

```
<tbody>
  {goods.map((item) => (
    <tr key={item.id}>
      <td>{item.id}</td>
      <td>{item.name}</td>
      <td>{item.status}</td>
      <td>{item.quantity}</td>
    </tr>
  ))}
</tbody>
```

---

#### Sorting

In order to sort, you need additional states to store the sort property and the sort order (ascending or descending). Perhaps like this:

```
const [sortProperty, setSortProperty] = React.useState<keyof Goods>("id");

const [isDesc, setIsDesc] = React.useState(false);
```

Clicking on your column headings would update those states.  You would apply the current values of `sortProperty` and `isDesc` to your `goods` array to get an ordered array before you render it.

Perhaps we want to reverse the order when clicking on the current sort column again, but use ascending order as the first sort when clicking on a different column.  We might create a function like this which we can use as the `onClick` handler for the `th` elements.

```
const handleColumnClick = (name: keyof Goods) => {
  const isCurrent = sortProperty === name;
  setSortProperty(name);
  setIsDesc(prev => isCurrent ? !prev : false);
}
```

```
<th scope="col" onClick={() => handleColumnClick("id")}>ID</th>
```

To apply the order, we can get help from [lodash's orderBy function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#orderBy).

```
const order = isDesc ? "desc" : "asc";
const rows = orderBy(goods, sortProperty, order);
```

We want to use this ordered variable `rows` in our `tbody` instead of the unordered `goods`.

---

#### Component Code

[Working Demo on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-sorting-v0rzy?file=/src/Table/index.tsx)

```
import React from "react";
import { getGoods, Goods } from "./data";
import { orderBy } from "lodash";

export const Question3: React.FC = () => {
  const [goods, setGoods] = React.useState<Goods[]>([]);

  const [sortProperty, setSortProperty] = React.useState<keyof Goods>("id");
  const [isDesc, setIsDesc] = React.useState(false);

  const handleColumnClick = (name: keyof Goods) => {
    const isCurrent = sortProperty === name;
    setSortProperty(name);
    setIsDesc((prev) => (isCurrent ? !prev : false));
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // need to define the function and call it separately
    const load = async () => {
      try {
        const data = await getGoods();
        setGoods(data);
      } catch (error) {
        // your Promise won't ever error, but an actual API might
      }
    };
    load();
  }, []);

  const order = isDesc ? "desc" : "asc";
  const rows = orderBy(goods, sortProperty, order);

  return (
    <table className="table table-striped table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col" onClick={() => handleColumnClick("id")}>
            ID
          </th>
          <th scope="col" onClick={() => handleColumnClick("name")}>
            Name
          </th>
          <th scope="col" onClick={() => handleColumnClick("status")}>
            Status
          </th>
          <th scope="col" onClick={() => handleColumnClick("quantity")}>
            Quantity
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {rows.map((item) => (
          <tr key={item.id}>
            <td>{item.id}</td>
            <td>{item.name}</td>
            <td>{item.status}</td>
            <td>{item.quantity}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
```

---

You have an error in your sandbox mixing up default and named exports.  It should be:

```
import {Question3 as Abc} from "./Table";
```

You also need to `export` the `interface Goods` from your `data.ts` file in order to use that type in your component.

Answer (score 0):

**in your table body do something similar to this**

```
<div className="table">
       {getGoods.data.map(goods=>(
           <tr>
               <td>{goods.id}</td>
               <td>{goods.name}</td>
               <td>{goods.status}</td>
                <td>{goods.quantity}</td>
           </tr>
       )
       )
       }
    </div>
```

Comment: check the sand box u created, i fixed it

Comment: Have you checked @jaro

Answer (score 0):

getGoods is promise and it takes time to resolve. until that point show loader.

```
export const Abc: React.FC = () => {

const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    (async () => {
        const dataResponse = await getGoods();
        setData(dataResponse);
    })().catch((e) => {
        console.error(e)
    }).finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
    })
},[])
return (
    <table className="table table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Status</th>
                <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            {loading && <tr>
                <td colSpan='3'>Loading....</td>
            </tr>}
            {data.map(goods => (
                <tr>
                    <td>{goods.id}</td>
                    <td>{goods.name}</td>
                    <td>{goods.status}</td>
                    <td>{goods.quantity}</td>
                </tr>
                ))}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
};
```

this will help you make sure that you get finalData in the

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

How are we getting the data from a promise? use

```
useState(handler, []) // [] so that is get called only once per component
const dataResponse = await getGoods(); // wait till promise resolves
```